# How to optimise mongodb query when using big $nin / $in array query?

Tags: mongodb, optimization, find

The query is build by:

1 - Going to redis, get a list of ids to use on $nin

2 - Going to mongodb, do a geoquery excluding users by using _id: $nin [ big list ]

My problem is that the users on $nin list is updated every second, and grows relatively fast ( and will grow forever )

edit 1:

i also have the same list saved on mongodb inas a property of a document. so if i could negate the _ids of the geoquery using a find in another collection it could work although i'm not sure if that is possible ( probably not? )

edit 2:

One way i thought is to push the user id to a "viewed_by" property, so then instead of doing 2 queries one to find the viewed articles and another one to find unread articles, i'll just do 1 query looking forward articles where the "id" of the user isn't contained in the document's 'viewed_by' property.

The problem then becomes the "viewed_by" property, it will grow bigger and bigger and might become slow query as well ?

Is there such thing as storing the values in a "sorted" way, so then when using filtering the query with $ne it won't need to lookup all the values of the viewed_by array ( using binary search or some other fast array lookup ) ?

edit 3:

Usage example: I have a database of documents and users that keeps growing, users search for documents with their own customised query, but they can't see the same document twice.

So basically i have to keep track of all the documents they already saw and keep excluding them from the next search results, as the results are customised for each user i have to keep track of what each user have seen.

Comment: What is the use case for this? I think you are on the highway to sadness if you are planning to query to `$nin` with a fast ever-growing array of `_id`s. Can you be more specific and show example documents and queries?

Comment: i just edited again and added my use case, i hope it's clear enough!

Comment: @kroe Did you solve this problem somehow? I have the same now and I plan to store all ids in "viewed_by" (i have another field name), because in my case I think mongo limits will not be exceeded (16Mb per document). But I would to know how did you solve this issue?

Comment: This issue was not really solved, it was worked-around accordingly to my application needs and limits. In the end we decided that the $nin / $in would have a limit in size and then once it gets full we take out the older ones from the array, like FIFO

Comment: depending on your case you could use something like REDIS to do the list intersection for you and then query mongo afterwards, that is definitely the best solution for many kinds of applications...